# I would like help optimising a triple for loop with an if in statement

Tags: python, python-3.x, data-science

I am doing a triple for loop on a dataframe with almost 70 thousand entries. How do I optimize it?

My ultimate goal is to create a new column that has the country of a seismic event. I have a latitude, longitude and 'place' (ex: '17km N of North Nenana, Alaska') column. I tried to reverse geocode, but with 68,488 entries, there is no free service that lets me do that. And as a student, I cannot afford it.

So I am using a dataframe with a list of countries and a dataframe with a list of states to compare to USGS['place']'s values. To do that, I ultimately settled on using 3 for loops.

As you can assume, it takes a long time. I was hoping there is a way to speed things up. I am using python, but I use r as well. The for loops just run better on python.

Any better options I'll take.

```
USGS = pd.DataFrame(data = {'latitide':[64.7385, 61.116], 'longitude':[-149.136, -138.655], 'place':['17km N of North Nenana, Alaska', '74km WNW of Haines Junction, Canada'], 'country':[NA, NA]})

states = pd.DataFrame(data = {'state':['AK', 'AL'], 'name':['Alaska', 'Alabama']})

countries = pd.DataFrame(data = {'country':['Afghanistan', 'Canada']})

for head in states:
    for state in states[head]:
        for p in USGS['place']:
            if state in p:
                USGS['country'] = USGS['country'].map({p : 'United 'States'})

# I have not finished the code for the countries dataframe
```

Comment: How are you meant to link `states` with `countries` ? Doesn't seem like you use the `countries` dataframe anywhere in your logic.

Comment: Can you share a sample output? I think you might get faster performance indexing the dataframe columns or using the groupby() method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do have options to do geocoding. Mapquest offers a free 15,000 calls per month. You can also look at using [geopy](https://pypi.org/project/geopy/) which is what I use.

```
import pandas as pd
import geopy
from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim


USGS_df = pd.DataFrame(data = {'latitude':[64.7385, 61.116], 'longitude':[-149.136, -138.655], 'place':['17km N of North Nenana, Alaska', '74km WNW of Haines Junction, Canada'], 'country':[None, None]})

geopy.geocoders.options.default_user_agent = "locations-application"
geolocator=Nominatim(timeout=10) 



for i, row in USGS_df.iterrows():
    try:
        lat = row['latitude']
        lon = row['longitude']

        location = geolocator.reverse('%s, %s' %(lat, lon))
        country = location.raw['address']['country']

        print ('Found: ' + location.address)

        USGS_df.loc[i, 'country'] = country

    except:
        print ('Location not identified: %s, %s' %(lat, lon))
```

**Input:**

```
print (USGS_df)
   latitude  longitude                                place country
0   64.7385   -149.136       17km N of North Nenana, Alaska    None
1   61.1160   -138.655  74km WNW of Haines Junction, Canada    None
```

**Output:**

```
print (USGS_df)
   latitude  longitude                                place country
0   64.7385   -149.136       17km N of North Nenana, Alaska     USA
1   61.1160   -138.655  74km WNW of Haines Junction, Canada  Canada
```

Comment: Thank you. This seems to have done what I want. It has been running for 12 hours. So we'll see when it finishes.

Comment: It took about a day and a half, but it worked. Thank you very much!

Comment: Ya that’s a long time. If you need to do it again, could be worth researching a faster method or Maybe even see if you can do it concurrently.